# wxPropertyGrid::EditorValidate() always returns true

Tags: wxwidgets

A user is editing a value in a property grid, then he clicks a button outside the property grid which executes code to read the property values.  Sometimes the OLD value of the property is read, rather than the new value which was being edited.  I have to tell the users that they must complete the editing, by hitting return or clicking on another property before clicking any buttons outside the grid.  They forget, and report a bug.

I would like to make this foolproof.  Perhaps by forcing the current edit to complete when the mouse leaves the property grid.

I know how to handle the mouse leaving event.  I do not know how to force the property grid to accept any partial edits.

I have tried, as a hint to the user,

```
pg = new wxPropertyGrid( ...
....
if( ! pg->EditorValidate() )
{
    SetStatusText("Please complete editing");
    return;
}
```

but EditorValidate() always returns true

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

wxPropertyGrid::CommitChangesFromEditor()

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_property_grid.html#a6e06d92a622237457fea00372df1eaae